# How to display array url values from custom field ( file upload )?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, metadata, custom-fields

I'm am currently working on an Album Gallery and I am using this CMB2 plugin

https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2

to create my custom fields. What I am using right now is the file_list field which allows me to upload multiple/bulk images.

But the problem is that I am not sure how to display each item. I would like to get the url of each item so I can use each as an image source.

What I am trying to achive is something like:

```
<li><img src="<?php echo $file_list; ?>" alt="" /></li>
```

Meaning, each item would be wrap in 'li img' and file link would be added as a src.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should contact the plugin team about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I've made it worked with this:

```
<?php 

            $count=0;
            if (is_array($album_files))
            {
                foreach ($album_files as $files)
                {
                  $count++;

                  if (1 == $count) {
                    echo
                    '<figure>',
                      '<img ','src="', $files , '" ','>',
                    '</figure>';
                  }
                }
            }

          ?>
```

Hopefully this can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps...

```
        <?php $meta_values =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yourprefix_demo_file_list', true);
foreach($meta_values as $meta_value) {
echo '<li><img src="'. $meta_value . '"/></li>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I figured it out actually, I posted my code below. Thanks for answering as well.